# Add validation in django admin master-detail interface (for detail records)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have the following example and I don't know how to set a validation error for each row in admin interface:

> refer to # add validation error for that row in forms.py

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class Foo(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField("Name", blank=True, max_length=300)

class Bar(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField("Name", blank=True, max_length=300)
   foo = models.ForeignKey('Foo', verbose_name='Foo')
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *
from .forms import *

class BarInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Bar
    formset = BarInlineFormset

@admin.register(Foo)   
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Foo
    inlines = [BarInline,]
```

forms.py

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class BarInlineFormset(forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        valid = True
        for item in data:
            if not item:
                break;
            if not item['name'].startswith('Bar'):
                valid = False
                # add validation error for that row

        if not valid:
            raise ValidationError('Form is not valid.')

        return data
```

> P.S. I'm using Django 1.8.x and Python 3.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a simple solution for this, work perfect:

admin.py

```
class BarInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Bar
    form = BarForm

@admin.register(Foo)   
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Foo
    inlines = [BarInline,]
```

forms.py

```
class BarForm(forms.models.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bar
        fields = ('name',)

    def clean(self):
      data = self.cleaned_data     
      if not item['name'].startswith('Bar'):
         raise ValidationError('Item is not valid.')
```

> So I did not use InlineFormSet and I did not use inlineformset_factory not at all and this is a complete solution that works not just fragments brought here by some untested search

Comment: I wonder how on earth is this different from what I suggested.

Answer (score 1):

To add validation to your inline formset you can create a custom Form and specify this form to the formset, rather than creating a custom base inline formset:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(MyForm, self).clean()
        for field in cleaned_data:
            # if some meaningful condition for field is met:
                # raise validation error
        return cleaned_data

    class Meta:
        model = ParentModel
        fields = ['fieldA', 'fieldB', ...]

BarInlineFormset = inlineformset_factory(ParentModel, Model, form=MyForm, extra=0, min_num=0)
```

Do not forget to properly configure your model form, especially its meta class to define model and fields.

Reference: [Django documentation: Model form Functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/models/), [Creating forms from models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/).

Comment: Dear @serjik, this is merely a code sample concerning the question you ask and not how to build modelforms. You need to define a meta for the modelform. I would recommend you to take a read on the documentation about forms.